# Problema con consulta MySql dentro de query PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mi codigo de php

```
$consulta = "SELECT 
    p.universidad, 
    COUNT(c.cod_cita) as TOTALES, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.universidad = 'Latina' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS latina,
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN p.universidad = 'UAM' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) AS uam
FROM citas as c 
    JOIN pacientes as p
        ON c.cedulaFK = p.cedula 
        AND c.fecha_cita >= '$fecha1' 
        AND c.fecha_cita <= '$fecha2' 
WHERE 
    c.cod_sedeFK = 2
";


Las variables de $fecha1 y fecha2 las obtengo de aca: 
$fecha1 = $sesion->get("fecha1");
 $fecha2= $sesion->get("fecha2");
```

Dicha consulta no funciona así, pero si cambio las fechas en el query de la siguiente manera:

```
AND c.fecha_cita >= '2018/12/01' 
AND c.fecha_cita <= '2018/12/31' //de esa manera si funciona.
```

Ya probé que las variables `$fecha1` y `$fecha2` estén "llenas", o que poseean una fecha, sin embargo, no funciona

Comment: Pero ¿qué formato tienen las fechas aquí: `$fecha1 = $sesion->get("fecha1");
 $fecha2= $sesion->get("fecha2");`, no vendrán con el año cambiado de posición o algo así? Deberías imprimir ambas variables para ver lo que te está arrojando la llamada a `get`

Comment: intenta hacerle un echo a la consulta para ver si recibe o no las fechas

Comment: Sobre el código: ese `CASE` lo puedes simplificar con `IF(p.universidad = 'Latina',1,0)`  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: para introducir una variable en un string has de hacerlo entre claves {}, lo que sería {$fecha1} y {$fecha2}, también puedes confirmar la query con un echo $consulta; y ver que query estás lanzando